# Yii2 extra parameter ajax in controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I need bulk delete for my grid. I have jquery script

```
  $activeMassScriptJS= <<<JS
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.product-update").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            var keys = $('#products-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
            $.get('mass-status-movie', {keylist : keys}, function(data) { alert(keys[0]);});
            return false;
    });
});
```

JS;

controller

```
public function actionMassdelete(){
    if (Yii::$app->request->post('keylist')) {
        $keys = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist');
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $model = Product::findOne($key);
            $model->delete();
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
}
```

it working for  address .../movie/index  but i need to working for address /movie/index?parameter=value 
how to do?

Comment: I can't quite understand your situation. As I got it, your JS is running at `/movie/index` and you need to send GET-request to `/movie/index?parameter=value`, right? But you have another URI in your script: `$.get('mass-status-movie'`... And the action provided is `/something/massdelete`...

Comment: Yes, i need sent get request. massdelete will remove all items  from grid.

Comment: Well, you're sending the request not to the action you've provided.

Comment: I know, i should use get method everywhere, but i don't know how  use extra parameter in controller

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confusing code. Your code is making a `get` request to the server, but then your action, which is not the one you sent the request to, is checking `post` parameters! You need to sort out what requests you are making, and check the values accordingly. Here are two scenarios;

**Case 1**
You keep the ajax call as a `get` request, so yor code is

```
$activeMassScriptJS= <<<JS
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button.product-update").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var keys = $('#products-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $.get('mass-status-movie', {keylist : keys}, function(data) { alert(keys[0]);});
    return false;
    });
});
```

The values that you have sent via the `get` request will now be available in two ways. At the action you pointed to, i.e.`actionMassStatusMovie()`, you can access them like this;

```
public function actionMassStatusMovie($keyList){
    //Your code here
}
```

You would use this if you always wanted the `keyList` parameter to be present.

You can also access the `get` parameters anywhere in your script like this `Yii::$app->request->get('keylist')`. In this case, you don't need  the $keyList parameter, so you can just use

```
public function actionMassStatusMovie(){
        $keyList = Yii::$app->request->get('keylist');
    }
```

**Case 2**

Alternatively, you can send the data via a `post` request. In this case, you don't use the parameter, just check it like you have been doing,

```
public function actionMassStatusMovie(){
        $keyList = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist');
    }
```

But to do this, you need to change your original javascript code to make a `post` request.

```
 $activeMassScriptJS= <<<JS
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.product-update").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            var keys = $('#products-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
            $.post('mass-status-movie', {keylist : keys}, function(data) { alert(keys[0]);});
            return false;
    });
});
```

`get` and `post` requests are different, and your code needs to be consistent in how they are being used!